# When I use css on radio buttons it causes the value not to go through when form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I'm using css on radio buttons for my rails form and when I submit the form the values do not show in my database, but when I take away the css the value does show in the database, so I realize it's something to do with my css, but what is causing it?

form.css

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #0AA8E5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;


  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #0AA8E5;
  color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #0AA8E5;
  &::after {
    color: hsla(215, 5%, 25%, 1);
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 45%, 1);
    content: "\f00c";
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;

    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.25);
  }
}
```

form.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.radio_button(:role, "startup", id: 'control_01', name: "select", value: 'startup') %>
        <label for="control_01">
          <h2>Startup</h2>
          <p>Join the startup side</p>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.radio_button(:role, "investor", id: 'control_02', name: "select", value: 'investor') %>
        <label for="control_02">
          <h2>Investor</h2>
          <p>Join the investor side</p>
        </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-success" %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: How are you selecting or clicking radio radio buttons from UI after setting display as none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden;`

display: none removes the element from the document flow,